# Unity3D SetActive freeze the UI panel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with hiding the UI panel in Unity. The code is called when a client is connected to the server.

```
void OnPlayerConnected(NetworkPlayer player) {
     gameObject.SendMessage("HideAllActiveUI", SendMessageOption.NoReceiverRequired);
}

void OnConnectedToServer() {
     gameObject.SendMessage("HideAllActiveUI", SendMessageOption.NoReceiverRequired);
}

public void HideAllActiveUI() {
     uiPanel.SetActive(false);
     gameUI.SetActive(true);
}
```

I have initialised all the neccessary variable however, the code doesn't hide the panel. Surprisingly, when I run it on the editor, it successfully hide the panel but when I run it with the player, the UI panel still exist and the gameUI appear even though the UI panel didn't disappear.

Comment: Is your gamobject active? From the docs: Note that messages will not be sent to inactive objects (ie, those that have been deactivated in the editor or with the SetActive function).

Comment: Yes. My gameobject is active. The sendmessage works but the UI not hiding. Apparently it freeze, all the button become non-clickable probably cause the gameUI became active, but the gameUI has a background image which supposedly cover the entire ui.

Comment: Are you sure that you are actually connecting to the server? If the connected functions never get called it cant call HideAllActiveUI

Comment: It is definitely connected to the server, as the gameUI became active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `SetActive` on the `gameObject` property of your panel, rather than on the panel directly:

```
uiPanel.gameObject.SetActive(false);
```